# How to develop a android service depend on a other service

Tags: android, service, dependencies

I have two service, Service A and  Service B.How to develop Service B depend on a Service A? When I start Service B,I should know if Service A is running.If Service A is running,start Service B .Else,not start Service B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you question is same with, how to know one service is running or not, right ;)

Android has `Activity Manager` to do your work.

```
public boolean checkService(String service) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (service.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Th String service should be your class name, for example : `com.app.Intent`

And this is a pseudocode. I don't make it detail because many ways to start your service, depend on how you use it.

```
if checkService("com.app.ServiceA") 
    running ServiceA;
running ServiceB;  // Because I see that ServiceB always still always run, not depend on ServiceA
```

Hope this help you :)